# Why i can't change variable in JLabel?

Tags: java

i just wanna count in jlabel. i think, I have tried all the solutions posted in the site but i couldn't find out any solution. I am a beginner, have one month to learn Java. I am sorry if my question is too stupid.

```
package asdf;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class asd extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
int a=0;  // variable
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                asd window = new asd();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public asd() {
    super();
    Timer time=new Timer(1000, this); 
    time.start(); 
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(20, 11, 137, 111);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    ***JLabel Jtable = new JLabel();
    Jtable.setBounds(0, 25, 127, 58);
    Jtable.setText("" + a);
    panel.add(Jtable);***

    System.out.println(a); //it is counting on console but in Jlabel variable is not.

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    a++;
    initialize();   
}
}
```

i just wanna count in jlabel. i think, I have tried all the solutions posted in the site but i couldn't find out any solution. I am a beginner, have one month to learn Java. I am sorry if my question is too stupid.

Comment: What is the **name** of the variable you want to change?

Comment: I'd recommend you only call the initialize() method once, when the class loads. Then move your Jtable.setText() to the actionPerformed() method.

Although your class is extending [subclassing] JFrame, so "this" should be an instance of JFrame; meaning you can use statements like "this.setBounds()" in your initialize() method.

Also, it's best practice to name your variables beginning with a lower case. [jTable instead of Jtable]

Comment: Hi @ Eee please follow the Java naming convention specified at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be initializing a new frame and all the components on every action performed, you should only be updating the text of the label. You can do this via JLabel.setText https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)

```
int a = 0;  // variable
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                asd window = new asd();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public asd() {
    super();
    Timer time=new Timer(1000, this); 
    time.start(); 
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */

private JLabel label;
private void initialize() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(20, 11, 137, 111);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    label = new JLabel();
    label.setBounds(0, 25, 127, 58);
    label.setText("" + a);
    panel.add(label);

    System.out.println(a); //it is counting on console but in Jlabel variable is not.

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    a++;

    label.setText("" + a);

}
```

Comment: billion times thanks  for your answer. i tried it before and there was an error : "label cannot be resolved". i loaf the entire day away. entire day i worked for write it : "label = new JLabel();" billion times thank you. You are hero. You are real Jon Snow.